# Unable to include .pdb files in NuGet package

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to include the .pdb files in my NuGet packages to assist with debugging, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I've added the following line to my .csproj file as recommended.  It's in the same PropertyGroup as AssemblyName, OutputType, TargetFrameworkVersion, etc.

```
<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
```

I'm using:

- VS 2017 v15.5.6
- NuGet v4.6.2
- Target framework: .NET Framework 4.5 (Shouldn't think this matters, but won't hurt saying so)

And have the following post build event:

```
nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)
nuget add $(ProjectName).@(VersionNumber).nupkg -source %PACKAGES_FOLDER%
```

I was using a nuspec file to get them in there, but this was messing with our build server.

All help appreciated.

Cheers
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I finally sorted out my NuGet issues.  The following info may help others.

- I placed the latest version of nuget.exe in my solution folder.
- I don't have any nuspec files.  This keeps our build server happy.
- I removed the AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder setting from my .csproj files.  This only appears to work for .NET Core and .NET Standard projects.  I confirmed this by creating three brand new VS 2017 projects.  The .NET Framework project was the only one that wouldn't pack (tested using `dotnet pack` instead of `nuget pack`).

I'm now using the following post build event in each of my projects:

```
del "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*.nupkg"
$(SolutionDir)nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -symbols -Prop Configuration=$(ConfigurationName)
$(SolutionDir)nuget add $(ProjectName).@(VersionNumber).symbols.nupkg -source C:\Packages
```

The first line just removes previously generated .nupkg files that pile up in the build folder.

Comment: Nope.  This doesn't work.  The pdb and source files are packaged along with the dll, everything looks good, but the debugger doesn't allow me to step into it.  I can however, use F12 and _Go To Declaration_.
I see the dreaded _The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document._ message.

Comment: Scratch that.  It does work.  I just needed to add my packages folder (i.e. C:\Packages) to Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> Symbols -- Symbol file (.pdb) locations